Synchronization of an unbounded crossbeam channel
If after creating a crossbeam unbounded channel I clone the sender multiple times and pass these to multiple threads and the single receiver to a separate thread, is the order of arrival of the messages sent from the different senders guaranteed on the receiving side?
